# Ruby on Rails session looses information. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, passenger

my ruby on Rails application should save some information in session. Directly after saving all Infomrations are in saved. I've checked this.

But after reloading the page oder linking to a second page the session is empty. 
Is there a reason for that?

Here is explained that the passenger Modul has a session handling:
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerStickySessions

But no how to enable ist.

Where is the mistake? In Passenger configuration or?

Comment: Seems like [session store](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session) is not configured in Rails application. Check it.

Comment: Okay i have seen there are lots of files in the config/initializers .... how can I run them? Or better queststion how Is a Ruby Application properly deployed? ... I've seen there is a capfile in root of application ... but I can't run it without errors

Comment: Can you please explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It often happens when you are using devise, in that case you need to sign in the user again with `sign_in` method,

```
sign_in user, bypass: true
```

where `user` is the current_user object

Comment: don't use anything of that..... i only store in session like this `session[:super_admin] = true`